# How to set the checking of initial values in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, initialization

I am making my first spring application. Trying for some better organizing, I met a problem:

- The application gets the initial values of attributes from some spring file springValues.
- Naturally, I have to check the values got.
- Where have I to put the limits, against which I have to check the initial values? These limits are the initial values, too, so, they will be in another spring file springLimits. Obviously, it is senseless to put values and limits into the same file - they are pieces of information of different levels - values are far more volatile that limits.
- Here comes the problem - I have to tie limits to values in code, for every property separately. It doesn't look consistent or convenient to me.

Is there some tool in Spring to find what limits belong to what values automatically? If I used property files instead of Spring, it would be trivial, but how to do it in Spring?

As I see now, I have to tie limits to value for every value separately. And working with properties I can tie limits to value by name, for example x->UpperX, LowerX. And I'll have to write ONE checking method for all values.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method in you java class to check for value limits and use that method as postConstruct to initialize your java bean. You can declare method for pre processing by using @PostConstruct or init-method or InitializingBean interface.

Comment: Where is "automatically" here? I have to tie limits to value for every value separately. And working with properties I can tie limits to value by name, for example x->UpperX, LowerX. And I'll have to write ONE checking method for all values.